# How do i parse .txt file contents with txt and ids to a dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, text

Below is a text file content with no header or quotes for the text data. How do i parse these in a dictionary.Each record in my file is on a new line Below is my text file content:

```
B00308CJ12 Bulletproof Salesman (2008)
189138922X Classical Mechanics
B0000CEP9J Fiesta Black 464 7-1/4-inch Salad Plate
B000HRH6IA Baby Blue Aurora Blue Gem Butterfly Belly Ring
B000002ERY Predicciones Leo
```

Using the code below is giving me an error. I am assuming that's because my sentences are not in quotes. What do i do to rectify and put these values in a dict

```
 f = open('file_path', 'r')
    answer = {}
    for line in f:
        k, v = line.strip().split(' ')
        answer[k.strip()] = v.strip()

    f.close()
```

ERROR:

> k, v = line.strip().split(' ')
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Edit after changes to code

```
 f = open('file_path', encoding="utf8")
    answer = {}
    for line in f:
        k, v = line.strip().split(' ')[0],line.strip().split(' ')[1:]
        answer[k] = v

    f.close()
```

Error :

> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
>       (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position
>   1266: invalid start byte

Comment: Are you intending to get `{'B00308CJ12':'Bulletproof Salesman (2008)',...}`? ie, each key on the left is then the unbroken string on the right?

Comment: Yes but my code is giving me something like this {'B00308CJ12':['Bulletproof', 'Salesman', '(2008)']}... That seems to be the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `{'B00308CJ12':'Bulletproof Salesman (2008)',...}`

Try this:

```
di={}    
with open(fn) as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        k,v=line.split(sep=None,maxsplit=1)
        di[k]=v.rstrip()

>>> di
{'B00308CJ12': 'Bulletproof Salesman (2008)', 
 '189138922X': 'Classical Mechanics', 
 'B0000CEP9J': 'Fiesta Black 464 7-1/4-inch Salad Plate', 
 'B000HRH6IA': 'Baby Blue Aurora Blue Gem Butterfly Belly Ring', 
 'B000002ERY': 'Predicciones Leo'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
k, v = line.strip().split(' ')
```

with

```
k, v = line.strip().split(' ')[0],line.strip().split(' ')[1:]
```

Your sentences have spaces in them, so you are getting more values than you are expecting

Answer (score 1):

The line `line.strip().split(' ')` actually splits each line of your text file into a list with the space character `' '` as delimiter producing an output like this one for the first line `['B00308CJ12', 'Bulletproof', 'Salesman', '(2008)']`. At this point if you want to create a dictionary, you need to decide what you want as key and value in your dictionary and get those values from the list using their corresponding indexes

Update about encoding

try reading the file with this line

```
f = open('file_path', encoding="utf8")
```

And to have `'Bulletproof Salesman (2008)'` as value you can use the join function

```
k, v = line.strip().split(' ')[0], " ".join(line.strip().split(' ')[1:])
```

Comment: Yeah i did and its throwing a error after half of my file was parsed as a dict  >>> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4062: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: What are you using as key? Can you update your original question with the new version of your code. Otherwise it will be hard to help. But this looks to me like a character encoding issue

Comment: i am taking the id as key and the sentence as value. i have updated the original question with the changes made and the error

Comment: as I expected it is a character encoding error. try reading the file specifying an encoding method like utf-8. See my updated answer

Comment: That throws a succeeding error - updated question again

Answer (score 1):

All answers put together the below code worked like a charm for the intended ie {'B00308CJ12': 'Bulletproof Salesman (2008)','189138922X': 'Classical Mechanics', ......}
Thanks all!!

```
answer = {}
with open('filepath','rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        k, v = line.strip().split(sep=None,maxsplit=1)[0],line.strip().split(sep=None,maxsplit=1)[1:]
        answer[k] = v
f.close()
```

Comment: Note: 1) `f.close()` is not necessary when you use `with` to open the file. 2) You are performing a second split unnecessarily with `k, v = line.strip().split(sep=None,maxsplit=1)[0],line.strip().split(sep=None,maxsplit=1)[1:]` You can just use tuple unpacking with `k,v=line.strip().split(maxsplit=1)` and `k` and `v` will get the proper values automatically.

Comment: not doing the second split is giving me an error >>k,v=line.strip().split(maxsplit=1)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)